# MATLAB 3D Plotting of Curves

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh, surf

I have 2 variables that I'm trying to graph and I can't figure out what functions to use in order to get the desired graph that I want. For example, I have a variable Depth which is a 70x12 matrix full of numbers. 12 is for each month of the year. I'm trying to graph Depth against Temperature which is also a 70x12 matrix full of numbers. The current way I am doing this is by using plot3 in a for loop with hold on and plotting each Depth vs Temperature curve separated by 1 on the z-axis. That looks like this:

[image]

And when rotated it looks like this:

[image]

However, what I want is some sort of meshgrid or surf inbetween my curves so that my graph would look something similar to this. I played around with surf and mesh a decent bit but I can't figure out how to use the data that I have stored in my variables to plot curves and a surface through the curves that looks anything like that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using `plot3` and `surf` but it is highly advisable to create matrices of both the depth and the temperature and the months using meshgrid.

The following code shows how to do this. I just made up some arbitrary temperature data called `temps` and then used `meshgrid` to turn the vector of depths and months into a grid corresponding to each entry in temps. Notice that because `M` and `D` are now matrices I don't need a `for` loop and can just `plot3` them all at once.

```
% create some data. The problem is that depths and months are vectors while
% I have a 70x12 grid o temperatures:
nd = 70;
depths = linspace(0, 1e3, nd);
months = 1:12;
temps = sin((1:nd)'*months/(nd*8));


% So make temps and depths matrices too:
[M, D] = meshgrid(months, depths)

% and now plot:
figure(112)
clf

% plot the surface from the matrices returned by meshgrid: notice I used
% facealpha to change the transparency:
hs = surf(temps, D, M, 'facealpha', .5);
hold all;

% now that we used meshgrid we can plot everything at once:
plot3(temps, D, M, 'linewidth', 3)

view(3)
grid on
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me understand what I needed in order to create a surf plot and the plot3 without a for loop was really helpful. Creating a 70x12 matrix for Days was all I needed to do since I already had 12 identical columns for Depth. Once I got that I was able to create a good surf plot and plot all the curves like you showed. Much thanks!